# Rewrite so it doesn't trigger error when no class is found

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the following function as when a user clicks somewhere to determine whether or not to hide a dropdown (in react). Everything works fine but when I click the body it logs the following.

I tried to rewrite it a couple of times but I can't find a way to resolve this issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
```

Function I use

```
if (!event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && this.state.active !== '') {
            this.setState({ active: ''});
        }
```

Comment: Wrap it all in `if (event.target != null && event.target.parentElement != null)`, since that's probably what's causing the null ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue as the following

```
if (this.state.active !== '' && !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && 
    (!event.target.parentElement || (!event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_user')))) 
    {this.setState({ active: ''});}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since both `event.target` and `event.target.parentElement` can be null/undefined, first you should check both of them to see if they are not null before you try to access any of their properties:

```
if (event.target && event.target.parentElement &&
    !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') &&
    !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') &&
    !event.target.className.includes('USERBARa_user') &&
    !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && 
    this.state.active !== '') {
        this.setState({ active: ''});
}
```

Comment: So when I click the body here it will not do `this.setState({active: ''});`? If so I want it to call that when either the `target` or the `parentElement` contains the class, if not default to `this.setState({active: ''});`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking here. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry, basically when a user clicks on anything other then the `target` or `target.parentElement` with classes mentioned I need to call `this.setState({ active: ''});`. When using your solution and clicking directly on the `HTML` tag it doesn't get called because you are checking if it has a parent first (which the `HTML` doesn't have.

Comment: So just add another `if` there :). Your original question was regarding the `undefined`, and in my answer I explained the cause.

Comment: solved it, thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.target &&` between `(` and `!event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications')`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `click` listener `event.target` can not be `undefined`, but if you catch the `body` element, `event.target.parentElement` will be `undefined`. So you can simply check if `body` caught

```
if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase == 'body' || !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_notifications') && !event.target.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && !event.target.parentElement.className.includes('USERBAR_user') && this.state.active !== '') {
            this.setState({ active: ''});
}
```